# How to SaveToPhotosAlbum crash in ios 11?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When we run code mention below to download and save image in photo library it crash automatic in ios 11. Please guide to solve this.

```
try 
{
    string uri = "https://www.xamarin.com/content/images/pages/branding/assets/xamagon.png";
    using (var url = new NSUrl(uri))
    using (var data = NSData.FromUrl(url))
    UIImage.LoadFromData(data).SaveToPhotosAlbum((image, error) => 
    {
        var o = image as UIImage;
        Console.WriteLine("error:" + error);
    });
} 
catch(Exception exx) 
{
    throw exx;
}
```

Comment: see this : https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60420

Answer (score 2):

**Swift - 4, Xcode 9 , IOS 11**

**Info.plist**

```
  <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
  <string> photos description.</string>

  <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
  <string> photos add description.</string>
```

**Add Code In Button Click**

```
let url = "https://www.xamarin.com/content/images/pages/branding/assets/xamagon.png"
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: url)!)

        let image:UIImage = UIImage(data: data)!

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
```

---

```
@objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if let error = error {
            // we got back an error!
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        } else {

            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "The image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read question carefully, it is for xamarin not iOS Swift

Answer (score 1):

You should add this, iOS 11 update

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to use Photo Library</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Right click on info.plist => Open with.. => Generic PList Editor.
Then inside the editor, add the key with your description, as shown in the attached image.